# How to parse TABLE text with Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I am using the nokogiri gem to parse an html table content in which I have a column with a list of names and some of those names are hyperlinked and some are not. When I use this code:

```
puts doc.xpath("//table//tr//td[1]/text()")
```

It skips the hyperlinked names. I can also get the hyperlinked names with this:

```
doc.xpath('//table//tr//td[1]//a[@href]').each do |link|
   puts link.text.strip
end
```

How can I get all names without having to do it twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all text in the cell, hyperlinked or not:

```
doc.xpath('//td[1]').each do |cell|
   puts cell.text.strip
end
```

Note: in a valid HTML document, a `td` will always be within a `table` and a `tr`. If you don't have any other selector requirements, you can simplify as above.